# Any idea to set q.op in pysolr?

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

The following code doesn't work.... any idea? thanks.
Couldn't find any reference about it...

```
import pysolr
....

self.solr = pysolr.Solr(solr_url, timeout=20)
docs = self.solr.search(q=q, q.op =q_op)
```

Can I just use self.solr.search(q=q, op =q_op) instead ?

Comment: what kind of exception do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use names with `.` directly in parameters in python, since they indicate an object reference (i.e. `datetime.datetime`, `solr.search()` etc.).

You can work around this by giving the properties as a dictionary which expands to parameters to the search function:

```py
results = solr.search(q=q, **{
            'q.op': 'AND'
          })
```

The [relevant code from pysolr](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/blob/master/pysolr.py#L718):

```py
"""
# Search with highlighting.
results = solr.search('ponies', **{
        'hl': 'true',
        'hl.fragsize': 10,
    })
"""

params = {'q': q}
params.update(kwargs)
```